# ActiveJob: Generate sitemap in response to content generation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, resque, rails-activejob, sitemap-generator-gem

In my Rails 4.2 app, I'm using sitemap_generator gem to generate sitemaps. And use Heroku scheduler to execute the rake task. I think it'd be better if the sitemap is generated when there is new content or execute a manual action from admin panel by clicking a button to generate sitemap and ping search engines.

So, in my ActiveJob, I'm executing following in background Job
`Rake::Task['sitemap:refresh'].invoke`

But it gives me the error that it doesn't know, how to build this task.

```
RuntimeError: Don't know how to build task 'sitemap:refresh' (see --tasks)
```

Thanks,

Comment: What does `heroku run bin/rake --tasks | grep 'sitemaps'` give you?

Comment: I managed to solve it by `%x(bundle exec rake sitemap:refresh)`

Answer (score 1):

Seems like the issue is the rake tasks are not loaded. You can first load the tasks and then invoke. Something listed below should help:

```
NameOfYourApp::Application.load_tasks
Rake::Task['sitemap:refresh'].invoke
```

Comment: this code didn't work for me i got this error
```RuntimeError
Don't know how to build task 'sitemap:refresh' (See the list of available tasks with `rake --tasks`)```